# Apply easing on jquery ui show?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-effects, easing

I'm trying to apply easing on a jquery ui show effect. Ideally the api would look something like this:

```
$(this).show('scale', {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'easeOutBounce', 
});
```

Currently the element is at display:none. I need to show it with the scaling effect and have an easing.

Do I have to separate the commands or is there something like this that would work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've tested it on jsfiddle and works:

```
$('.div1').show('scale', {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'easeOutBounce', 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tenshimsm/AUM6d/1/

Comment: This didn't work last year. Must have been an update on jquery's side. sweet in any case thanks

Comment: Last year?! Ooooops! Didn't see it.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove comma `(,)` after `easeOutBounce` then it should work

```
$(this).show('scale', {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'easeOutBounce' 
});
```

Comment: I still get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score -1):

Check firebug, when using code example it adds some hidden characters:

```
            jQuery('#search-container .fa-search').toggle('scale', {duration: 1000,easing: 'easeOutBounce'});â€‹
            jQuery('#homepage-search').toggle('scale', {duration: 1000,easing: 'easeOutBounce'});â€‹
```